# Number of Projects limits per account on GCP

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am new to GCE and I see there is a quota for all the resources I create under a project / region, but I do not see the projects. How many projects can a user create?

Comment: Do you mean how many cloud projects can be created under one user ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, an account may allow the developer to register up to 25 free applications and an unlimited number of paid applications, which is stated at doc of [How many applications can I create with Google App Engine?](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/general#create).